# Use jQuery to select multiple elements with .eq()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I want to select a subset of tds from a table.

I know before hand what the indexes are, but they are effectively random (not odd or even indexes, etc).

For instance say I want to select the 0th, 5th and 9th td.

```
indexesToSelect = [0, 5, 9];

// 1) this selects the one by one
$('table td').eq(0)
$('table td').eq(5)
$('table td').eq(9)


// 2)this selects them as a group (with underscore / lodash)
var $myIndexes = $();

_.forEach(indexesToSelect, function (idx) {
    $myIndexes = $myIndexes.add($('table td').eq(idx));
});
```

So (2) works and I am using that, but I wonder if there is a more natural way using jQuery.

Something like passing `.eq()` an array of indexes? (that doesn't work)

```
// does not work
$('table td').eq([0, 5, 9])
```

If not I will write a small plugin for something like `.eqMulti(array)`.

Note: there is no class that these tds share exclusively, so selecting based on class won't work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'd do it with [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/):

```
var elements = $("table td").filter(function(i) {
    return $.inArray(i, indexesToSelect) > -1;
});
```

Another [*more ugly*] way is mapping to a selector:

```
var elements = $($.map(indexesToSelect, function(i) {
    return "td:eq(" + i + ")";
}).join(","), "table");
```

Comment: I think first one is quite handsome.

Answer (score 8):

I wrapped VisioN's filter method into a jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.eqAnyOf = function (arrayOfIndexes) {
    return this.filter(function(i) {
        return $.inArray(i, arrayOfIndexes) > -1;
    });
};
```

So now usage is nice and clean:

```
var $tds = $('table td').eqAnyOf([1, 5, 9]);
```

Comment: Nice! Worked a treat in my new project.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
   $('table td:eq(0), table td:eq(5), table td:eq(9)')
```

Comment: Well, this will do it, but the array of indexes I want is not constant. It would need a function to translate the array into a string like the one you give here. But, for known indexes this is good.

Comment: @Sean So `'table td:eq(' + array.join('), table td:eq(') + ')'`?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('table td').filter(':eq(' + indexesToSelect.join('), :eq(') + ')')
```