# add multiple index in eq() function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I would like to add the code below to my content :

```
jQuery( ".pt-cv-content:eq(11)" ).attr( "id" , "content11" );
```

but I was wonder that

> Could I add multiple index in eq()?

For example :

```
eq(9,10,11).....
```

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213158/use-jquery-to-select-multiple-elements-with-eq

Comment: `id` of element should be unique. Setting elements at index `9,10,11` to `"content11"` would create duplicate `id`s in `document` . What is expected result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't, you need multiple selector like so :

```
jQuery( ".pt-cv-content:eq(11), .pt-cv-content:eq(12)" ).attr( "id" , "content11" );
```

Or you can store index into an array and loop over it :

```
var arr = [11,12]; // index 11 and 12
$.each(arr, function(i,e){   
  // this will defined same id name
  // which are not valid
  // as ID must be unique
  // unless you defined it by dynamic values there
  $('.pt-cv-content').eq(e).attr( "id" , "content11" );
});
```

**Noted :** You should use dynamic content as ID must be unique.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/uvLfv9fL/)**

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazail Setting `.pt-cv-content` elements at both index `11` , `12`, respectively would create duplicate `id`s in document ?

Comment: @guest271314 : yeah, seems so. But the point mentioned there is for multiple selector.

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali _"No, you can't, you need multiple selector"_ Should be possible using `:lt()` , `:gt()`  _"yeah, seems so. But the point mentioned there is for multiple selector. "_ , see post

Comment: @guest271314 ; OP asking about `eq(9,10,11)`, then the answer for that question is `No, you can't, you need multiple selector`, by the way i'm almost forgot about `:lt and :gt`. Your answer is more better.

Comment: @guest271314 : yes of course only first matched element are triggered when selecting using `#content11`. But what about using `$('[id="content11"]')`? I'm wondering what OP actually want to do with that case.

Answer (score 0):

Note

`id` of element should be unique. Setting elements at index `9`,`10`,`11` respectively, to `"content11"` would create duplicate `id`s in `document` .

Not certain what expected result is ?

---

Try substituting setting element `class` for `id` to avoid setting duplicate `id`s in `document`.

To select multiple elements between indexes within a collection of element , try using `:lt()` , `:gt()`

```js
$("div:lt(12):gt(8)").attr("class", "content11")
```

```css
.content11 {
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div>0</div>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
<div>11</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>13</div>
<div>14</div>
<div>15</div>
<div>16</div>
```