# Elegant way to select html elements 1,2,5,6 ...with unknown number of elements/

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im looking for elegant way to select only divs on left hand side (marked green).
Number of elements is unknown, so i cannot rely on     `.eq()` or any other function used for filtering elements. 
Thank you for any advice.

[image]

Html:

```
<div class="row">

<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is the number of elements per row known?

Comment: please share the html , is it div or table using row and td

Comment: You can calc the number of element per row, and change style every (number element per row/2)

Comment: There is only one row (div which holds all elements).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use jQuery to select multiple elements with .eq()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213158/use-jquery-to-select-multiple-elements-with-eq)

Comment: What is row has `5` divs ?

Comment: If the div dimentions are known and all equals like in your drawing, you could use the `offset().left` value in a each loop...

Comment: If you have a way of telling how many elements per row (before going to 'new line') you can select lefts with nth-child...

Comment: What is row has 5 divs ? - it may have even 100... I said, that number is unknown,

Comment: Can you include `css`, `js` at Question demonstrating how elements are currently being selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each div... If its left offset is less than the 3rd one...
It has to be selected.

```
//Find the offset position of the 3rd div
offset3 = $(".col-sm-6").eq(2).offset().left;

$(".col-sm-6").each(function(){
    if($(this).offset().left < offset3){
        SelectIt = $(this).children("div");  // Select the "green" inner div

    // Do something with SelectIt...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
//Select the first 2 elements of each row
var rowSize = 4;  
$("div.col-sm-6").filter(function() {
    return $(this).index() % rowSize < 2;
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
$("div.col-sm-6").filter(function() {
 return $(this).index() % 4 < 2
}).addClass('selected');
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">

<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div>1
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div>2
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div>3
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div>4
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div>5
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div>6
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div>7
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div>8
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [**first-child**](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) & [**nth-child**](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/).
Hope this snippet will be useful

```
$("#demoTable tr td:first-child").addClass("myClass");
$("#demoTable tr td:nth-child(2)").addClass("myClass");
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/kL2tqnze/1/)

Note: I tried with table you can check with `div.row`